# How to modify delegate to set a property of its return value in certain cases

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

I apologize for the crappy title, I have no idea how to put this into words.

### Assume the following scenario:

A Holiday struct implementing this interface:

```
public interface IHoliday
{
    HolidayName Name { get; }
    DateTime Date { get; }
    bool IsRegional { get; set; }
}
```

A HolidayCalculator class with several methods to calculate various holidays based on the given year:

```
public static class HolidayCalculator
{
    public static IHoliday GetAssumptionDay(int year)
    {
        CheckYear(year);
        return new Holiday(GetHolidayName(), new DateTime(year, 8, 15));
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

A HolidayFunc delegate and a HolidayStateMap class which inherits from Dictionary to map certain holidays to their respective states:

```
public delegate IHoliday HolidayFunc(int year);

public class HolidayStateMap : Dictionary<State, List<HolidayFunc>>
{
    public HolidayStateMap()
    {
        // add keys (State) with nation-wide holidays

        // add state specific holidays
        this[State.Bavaria].AddRange(new HolidayFunc[]
        {
            HolidayCalculator.GetEpiphany,
            HolidayCalculator.GetCorpusChristi,
            HolidayCalculator.GetAllSaintsDay
        });
    }
}
```

To get all holidays for a given state you go:

```
var holidayFunctions = _holidayStateMap[state];
var holidays = holidayFunctions.Select(function => function(year));
```

---

### The Question:

Some holidays, in some states, are celebrated in certain regions only. Meaning Assumption Day could be celebrated in all regions of one state but only in some regions of another.

I would now like to set the `IsRegional` property when the delegate is invoked for state1 but not for state2. All this, without changing my current setting.

Is it possible in some way to intercept the return value (`Holiday`) of the delegate I'm calling and inject a `true` into the `IsRegional` property where necessary. Maybe by wrapping my delegate  I am imagining something like this when populating the `HolidayStateMap`:

```
if (includeRegional)
{
    this[State.Bavaria].AddRange(new HolidayFunc[]
    {
        HolidayCalculator.GetAssumptionDay.AsRegional,
        HolidayCalculator.GetPeaceFestival.AsRegional
    });

    // and others...
{
```

which would then return the respective `Holiday` but with IsRegional set to true.

Going for an extension method, I'd picture the implementation to look somewhat like this:

```
public static IHoliday AsRegional(this HolidayFunc func, int year)
{
    var holiday = func.Invoke(year);
    holiday.IsRegional = true;
    return holiday;
}
```

(I know I would need an instance of the delegate for this to work)

Maybe someone can come up with a neat solution, I'm kinda stuck.
Thanks in advance.

PS: I know I might be overengineering this, but well..

Comment: Why do you want to add them with `AddRange`, what if you use a foreach loop and `if` you want to `includeRegional`, you use the `Add` for that item.

Comment: I have no collection to iterate over. I am referencing static methods of the HolidayCalculator class. Even though I could get all methods through reflection, I see no benefit in that, since I have no criteria I could base a decision on (whether to add a holiday to a state or not). This has to be hard-coded (or set thorugh configuration) in a way.

Also, my problem is not how to add holidays for certain states, but how to modify the return value of the respective calculators in specific cases.

Comment: I see the collection over here: `new HolidayFunc[] { HolidayCalculator.GetAssumptionDay.AsRegional, HolidayCalculator.GetPeaceFestival.AsRegional }` You can iterate over it.  (store it in a variable or put it directly in a foreach loop

Comment: Okay, I get what you're referring to now. Still, I see no benefit in iterating over the state specific collection of holidays, since regionality is no subject to a specific holiday, but to a specific state. To clarify: Assumption Day is a regional holiday in Bavaria so only celebrated in certain communes in the state of Bavaria - on the other hand, Assumption Day is a state-wide holiday in the state of Saarland. I want Assumption Day to pop up in both states - when searching for holidays state-wise - but with the `IsRegional` flag only set in the bavarian result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god.

I basically answered the question myself in the description:

> (I know I would need an instance of the delegate for this to work)

The solution was:

```
if (includeRegional)
{
    this[State.Bavaria].AddRange(new HolidayFunc[]
    {
        new HolidayFunc(HolidayCalculator.GetAssumptionDay).AsRegional, 
        new HolidayFunc(HolidayCalculator.GetPeaceFestival).AsRegional
    });
}
```

Sorry for that.
Thank you @Jeroen van Langen for trying though.